# Angular 2: Load Component Based on service response

Tags: angular

I have 10 components in my app, while I call Home route I want to load dynamic components base on Home service response.

**Home page component**

[image]

Code will execute like,
Home component - > Call HTTP Service -> returns me list name of array component name 
[e.g ]

[image]
-> Now I want to append 2 components in content area

Page will render like 
[image]

Comment: I already done stick component loading by doing this code.  https://plnkr.co/edit/AvXNQZrSU28NaM3bzYA2?p=preview

Comment: where is the widget1 and widget2 components are physically available? create a partial working model in plunker instead of having the code in  `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen the doc about [dynamic component loading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html)? It shows how you can dynamically insert components into the DOM.

More specifically, there are a few things you need to pay attention to:

**1) Define an anchor point where the components will be inserted**

You can do that with a template variable (`#content`):

```ts
@Component({
  template: `
    <nav>...</nav>

    <!-- This is where your components will be inserted -->
    <div class="container" #content></div>

    <footer>...</footer>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('content', {read: ViewContainerRef}) content: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private componentFactory: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadComponents();
  }

  loadComponents() {
    // Here, fetch the components from the backend
    // and insert them at the anchor point.
  }
}
```

**2) Get the component CLASSES to insert and add them to the DOM**

The problem is that your backend returns component names **as strings**, but `ComponentFactoryResolver` expects **classes**.

You need to *map component names to actual classes*. You could use a custom object for this:

```ts
import {Widget1Component} from '../widget/widget1.component';
import {Widget2Component} from '../widget/widget2.component';
const componentsRegistry = {
  'Widget1Component': Widget1Component
  'Widget2Component': Widget2Component
};
```

Now the `loadComponents()` method is easier to write:

```ts
loadComponents() {
  // Fetch components to display from the backend.
  const components = [
    { name: 'widget1', componentName: 'Widget1Component' },
    { name: 'widget2', componentName: 'Widget2Component' }
  ];
  // Insert...
  let componentClass, componentFactory;
  for (let c of components) {
    // Get the actual class for the current component.
    componentClass = componentsRegistry[c.componentName];
    // Get a factory for the current component.
    componentFactory = this.componentFactory.resolveComponentFactory(componentClass);
    // Insert the component at the anchor point.
    this.content.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

**3) Do not forget to add the dynamic components to `entryComponents`**

Dynamically loaded components have to be added to their NgModule's `entryComponents` array:

```ts
@NgModule({
  // ...
  entryComponents: [Widget1Component, Widget2Component, ...]
  // ...
})
export class AppModule{ }
```